# How to declare both method in routing.yml Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, routes, yaml, http-method

I want to declare both methods **GET** and **POST** for a same route in my routing.yml.

According [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) it's possible with annotations like that :

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/{id}")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
```

But how to **YAML** ? I tried different things :

```
contact_envoi:
    pattern:  /contact-envoi
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:contactEnvoi }
    requirements:
        sf_method: ['get','post']
```

and

```
...
    requirements:
        _method: { 'GET', 'POST' }
```

but it still doesn't work ... Please help, I found nothing in the documentation about that.

Comment: As of Symfony 2.2, the way to declare method requirements has changed. From [`requirements._method:`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements) to [`methods:`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements). You need to use `contact_envoi.methods: ['GET', 'POST']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Touki for his comment, it works!

I had to declare twice the same URL on two separate shares and each with their own method as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements) for Symfony 2.1 and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements) for Symfony 2.2.

```
contact:
    path:     /contact
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:contact }
    methods:  [GET]

contact_process:
    path:     /contact
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:contactProcess }
    methods:  [POST]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the same route with the GET and POST methods.

```
contact:
path:     /contact
defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:contact }
methods:  ['GET','POST']
```

Then manage in your controller the method used.

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

just remove the methods

```
contact:
  path:     /contact
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:contact }
```